# compare columns for a table in different 2 databases

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I got 1 table in 2 different databases, in a database the number of columns are 284 columns in the other databse the number of columns are 281 columns so there are 3 columns missing.
is there a query (not a tool as I have found out somthing called *compare it* ) where it can help to find the missing columns ?
example:

> database 1 
>   column1
>   column2
>   column3
>   column4
>   column5
>   column6
>
> database 2 
>   column1
>   column2
>   column3
>
> column5
>   column6

In the above example column 4 is missing, is there a query in sybase can tell me what is the missing column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two Temporary Tables for the two tables in two different databases, suppose #TableColumns1 and #TableColumns2

```
CREATE TABLE #TableColumns1(ColumnName VARCHAR(255))
CREATE TABLE #TableColumns2(ColumnName VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO #TableColumns1
SELECT SC.column_name
FROM SYS.SYSCOLUMN SC, SYS.SYSTABLE ST 
WHERE SC.table_id = ST.table_id AND ST.table_name = '<DatabaseName1.TableName1>';

INSERT INTO #TableColumns1
SELECT SC.column_name
FROM SYS.SYSCOLUMN SC, SYS.SYSTABLE ST 
WHERE SC.table_id = ST.table_id AND ST.table_name = '<DatabaseName2.TableName2>';
```

Now Create one more Temporary table #MissingTableColumns which will contain the actual results of the missing columns

```
CREATE TABLE #MissingTableColumns(ColumnName VARCHAR(255), TableName VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO #MissingTableColumns
(ColumnName, TableName)
SELECT ColumnName, '<Table1Name>'
FROM #TableColumns1, #TableColumns2 
WHERE #TableColumns1.ColumnName *= #TableColumns2.ColumnName

INSERT INTO #MissingTableColumns
(ColumnName, TableName)
SELECT ColumnName, '<Table2Name>'
FROM #TableColumns1, #TableColumns2 
WHERE #TableColumns1.ColumnName =* #TableColumns2.ColumnName
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Brilliant nice answer Abhishek